# Apache httpd.conf shows gibberish

Tags: apache, wampserver, httpd.conf

I am using  a 64 bit windows 7 and Wampserver 2.5. I want to change the default port from 80 to 8080. But  httpd.conf file is nothing like the one shown in tutorial. Mine is full of random words.

I am sorry I am new, and still learning how to use this site.

[image: this is what my conf fle looks like]

Comment: I answered but since this is about server software I think it should have been posted on the superuser or webmasters stackexchange site.

Answer (score 2):

The file is OK, but it doesn't look right because it seems to be using linux newlines (\n) instead of windows newlines (\r\n).  One solution is to use a better editor (such as EditPlus), which will interpret the newlines properly even if they're linux.

Comment: Thank you . I tried opening it with notepad++ . It worked well.

Comment: @kinley619 please mark it as the answer so others don't waste time here looking to answer it.

Comment: Once you open it with notepad++ make sure you save the file in windows foramt so the newlines get changed to windows newlines.